# Override View Model Property Name

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to be able to override the display name of a property programatically.

I have a view model which has display names defined.

```
    [Display(Name = "Reference")]
    public string Reference { get; set; }
```

I created an overload for the LabelFor() extension which takes an string override parameter.

```
public static MvcHtmlString LabelFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, string applicationVariableOverride)
{
    if (applicationVariableOverride != null)
        return new MvcHtmlString(applicationVariableOverride);
    else
        return System.Web.Mvc.Html.LabelExtensions.LabelFor<TModel, TValue>(htmlHelper, expression);
}
```

...calling it like this:

```
@Html.LabelFor(x => x.Reference, "New Reference Display Name")
```

This works great for labels but won't work for validation messages that use these properties as the text being set is dynamic depending on what message is being displayed. Instead I would like to pass (or set) the display name of property in this function.

```
public static MvcHtmlString ValidationMessageFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, string applicationVariableOverride)
{
    // set display name

    return System.Web.Mvc.Html.ValidationExtensions.ValidationMessageFor<TModel, TProperty>(htmlHelper, expression);
}
```

Do I access the attribute directly and try and access one of its properties (display name) or is there another simpler way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can override the whole error message. If you want to replace just part of error message (property display name) - it is already too late. This error message is being set via `ValidationAttribute` into `ModelState` earlier (i.e. before view comes into play).

```
// error is already in the collection
string fullHtmlFieldName = htmlHelper.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(expression);
ModelErrorCollection errors = htmlHelper.ViewData.ModelState[fullHtmlFieldName].Errors;
```

What you can do is hack - decorate your property with some odd keyword like

```
[Display(Name = "$myplaceholder$")]
public string Reference { get; set; }
```

And in your method

```
 var oldMessage = System.Web.Mvc.Html.ValidationExtensions.ValidationMessageFor<TModel, TProperty>(htmlHelper, expression);
 var newMessage = oldMessage.ToString().Replace("$myplaceholder$", applicationVariableOverride);
 return new MvcHtmlString(newMessage);
```

But overall it smells like XY problem - question is why don't you want to override `DisplayNameAttribute` instead.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I would like to override the attribute as this would be the logical/correct place to set the display name, but it won't let me pass anything that isn't a constant...